# I am editing php codes ( in index.php) to my website but I cant see any changes on the website

Tags: php, web

[image]Here is the part of my index.php::

```
<?php include("header.php"); 
$containerClass="container"; $rowClass="row";
?>
<div id='wrapper'>
<div class='<?php print $containerClass; ?>' >
<?php
if(($ptype=="" && $fullScreenEnabled!="true") || $ptype=="home" ||     $ptype=="viewMemberListing" || $ptype=="viewFullListing" || ($ptype=="showOnMap"      && $fullScreenEnabled!="true") || $ptype=="adminOptions"  ||     $ptype=="UpdateAdminOptions" || $ptype=="allMembers" || $ptype=="contactus" ||     $ptype=="page" || $_GET["cpage"]==1){
if($ptype=="viewMemberListing") $reextraMessage=" ".$relanguage_tags["your     listings"]." ";
else $reextraMessage=" ".$relanguage_tags["all listings"]." ";
?>

<div class='<?php print $rowClass; ?>'>
<div class='col-md-4 col-lg-4 sbar'>
  <div id="sidebar">

  <div id="sidebar1">
  <div class='a_block'>
    <h3><?php print $relanguage_tags["Search"].$reextraMessage; ?></h3>
    <?php include("reSearchForm.php"); ?>

</div>
  </div>  <!-- end #sidebar1 -->
```

To this I add:

```
<div id="sidebar1">
<div class='a_block'>
<h3><?php print $relanguage_tags["Add Listing"].$reextraMessage; ?></h3>
<?php include("submitReListing.php"); ?>

</div>
</div>  <!-- end #sidebar1 -->
```

// submitReListing.php is already there on my website and working but i just want this button to be on the home page so that users can search and submit listing from the homepage.

After I added the second part, I go to filezilla and it asks me if i want to upload file back to the server. I select yes. ( Do i need to check "Finish editing and delete local file"??) But i dont see any changes in my website.

Please suggest.
I am new to php so please bear with these questions. I can also provide the entire index file or other file if required. Thanks

Entire code:

```
<?php include("header.php"); 
$containerClass="container"; $rowClass="row";
?>
<div id='wrapper'>
<div class='<?php print $containerClass; ?>' >
<?php
if(($ptype=="" && $fullScreenEnabled!="true") || $ptype=="home" ||     $ptype=="viewMemberListing" || $ptype=="viewFullListing" || ($ptype=="showOnMap"      && $fullScreenEnabled!="true") || $ptype=="adminOptions"  || $ptype=="UpdateAdminOptions" || $ptype=="allMembers" || $ptype=="contactus" ||     $ptype=="page" || $_GET["cpage"]==1){
if($ptype=="viewMemberListing") $reextraMessage=" ".$relanguage_tags["your     listings"]." ";
else $reextraMessage=" ".$relanguage_tags["all listings"]." ";
?>

<div class='<?php print $rowClass; ?>'>
<div class='col-md-4 col-lg-4 sbar'>
<div id="sidebar">

<div id="sidebar1">
<div class='a_block'>
<h3><?php print $relanguage_tags["Search"].$reextraMessage; ?></h3>
<?php include("reSearchForm.php"); ?>

</div>
</div>  <!-- end #sidebar1 -->

<div id="sidebar2">
<div class='a_block'>
<h3><?php print $relanguage_tags["Add listing"].$reextraMessage; ?></h3>
<?php include("submitReListing.php"); ?>

</div>
</div>  <!-- end #sidebar1 -->




<?php  if(trim($sidebarad)!=""){ ?>
<div id='sidebarad1'><?php print $sidebarad; ?></div>
<?php } ?>
</div> <!-- end #sidebar -->
</div>
<div class='col-md-8 col-lg-8'>  
<div id="mainContent">
<div id='reResults'>
<?php if($ptype=="viewFullListing") include("viewFullListing.php"); ?>
<?php if($ptype=="adminOptions" || $ptype=="UpdateAdminOptions")     include("adminOptions.php"); ?>
<?php if($ptype=="allMembers") include("allMembers.php"); ?> 
<?php if($ptype=="showOnMap"  && $fullScreenEnabled!="true") print "<div     id='mapResults'></div>" ?> 
<?php if($ptype=="contactus") include("contactus.php"); ?>
<?php if($ptype=="page"){ include("page.php"); $fullScreenEnabled="false"; }     ?>
<?php if($_GET["cpage"]==1) include("pluginPage.php"); ?>
<?php if($ptype=="categoriesEdit") loadPage("categoriesEdit.php"); ?>
</div>    
</div><!-- end #mainContent -->
</div> 
</div>

<?php
} 

if($fullScreenEnabled=="true"){
?>
<div style="width:100%;">

<div style="width:248px;" id='mapSidebar' >
<div id='showbar' data-original-title="<?php print $relanguage_tags["Show the     sidebar"]; ?>"></div>
<div id="sidebar" class='ui-widget-content'>
<div id="sidebarTabs"><div id='hidebar' data-original-title="<?php print $relanguage_tags["Hide the sidebar"]; ?>"></div>
<ul>
<li><a href="#sidebar1"><?php print __("Search"); ?></a></li>
<li id='resultTab'><a href="#sidebarResults"><?php print __("Results"); ?> </a></li>
</ul>       
<div id="sidebar1">
<div class='a_block'>
<!-- <div id="logo2"></div> -->
<h3><?php print $relanguage_tags["Search"].$reextraMessage; ?></h3>
<?php include("reSearchForm.php"); ?>
</div>

<?php  if(trim($sidebarad)!=""){ ?>
 <div id='sidebarad1'><?php print $sidebarad; ?></div>
<?php } ?>

</div>  <!-- end #sidebar1 -->
<div id='sidebarResults'></div>
</div>


</div> <!-- end #sidebar -->
</div> <!-- end mapSidebar -->



<div style="width:80%;" id='mapContainer'>
<div id="mainContent"><div id='mapResults'></div><div id='theListing'></div>        <div id='MapLoadingImage'><img src='images/maploading1.gif' alt='loading' />        </div>
<div id='modeButton'><a class='btn btn-primary btn-large' href='index.php?    ptype=home&<?php print str_replace("ptype=", "",htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])); ?>'><i class='icon-align-    justify'></i> <?php print $relanguage_tags["Switch to text mode"]; ?></a></div>
</div> <!-- end span8 -->
</div>

</div> <!-- end row -->
<div class="nolisting alert alert-info"><a class="close"      onclick="$('.alert').hide()" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">x</a>
<h4 style="text-align:'center'"><?php print $relanguage_tags["No listings found     for your search criteria"]; ?>.
<?php if($isThisDemo=="yes") print "The demo has limited listings."  ?> 
</h4></div>
<?php 
}

if($ptype=="checklogin") loadPage("checklogin.php");
if($ptype=="submitReListing") loadPage("submitReListing.php");
if($ptype=="addReListing") loadPage("addReListing.php");
if($ptype=="editReListingForm") loadPage("editReListingForm.php");
if($ptype=="updateReListing") loadPage("updateReListing.php");
if($ptype=="myprofile") loadPage("myprofile.php");
if($ptype=="languagetags" || $ptype=="updateLanguageTags") loadPage("languagetags.php");
if($ptype=="categories" || $ptype=="updateCategories") loadPage("categories.php");
if($ptype=="pricerange" || $ptype=="updatePriceRange")   loadPage("pricerange.php");
if($ptype=="countries" || $ptype=="updateCountries") loadPage("countries.php");
if($ptype=="towns" || $ptype=="updateTowns") loadPage("towns.php");
if($ptype=="addeditpage") loadPage("addeditpage.php");
if($ptype=="oodle" || $ptype=="updateOodle")     loadPage("plugins/oodle/options.php");

?>
<!--
<div id="a_c" style="display:none;"><?php print $authorization_code; ?></div>
<div id="p_c" style="display:none;"><?php print md5($purchase_code); ?>    </div>
-->
</div>
</div>

<?php 
//if($fullScreenEnabled!="true") 
include("footer.php"); ?>
```

Comment: Sounds like an opcode cache issue to me... Have you tried restarting the web server?

Comment: When you say you add, do you mean you replace? As you shouldn't be adding it, as you'll have two div IDs with the same name, which is incorrect syntax. When the Filezilla dialog box appears asking if you want to delete the local copy, take a note of where the upload path is, make sure it's on the server, and not on a local copy.

Comment: @Lee so Ill should change the div id to anything . like sidebar 2 . and check the upload path. how do i do that? I am infact connected to the server. How do i make sure if the changes are made to the files in the server?

Comment: @Lee I am attaching a screenshot of the popup it gives me. I do not check the "finish editing and delete local file" , Is that what im doing wrong? Should I check it?

Comment: If you're adding in another sidebar, then yes it should have a unique ID. You shouldn't have to, although you could do it anyway. It may or may not help. First off all, test what you are editing is actually being uploaded, by changing a heading to something with some extra letters, and see if those changes are applied.

Comment: This is the status when I update the file on server .........................................................................................................................                                                                     Status: Connected
Status: Starting upload of C:\Users\SHREYA BISHT\AppData\Local\Temp\fz3temp-1\index.php
Status: File transfer successful, transferred 5,284 bytes in 1 second
Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/public_html"...
Status: Directory listing of "/public_html" successful

Comment: can you just add a dummy text instead of the php code and then check whether the changes are reflected i.e try doing this:                           <div id="sidebar1">
<div class='a_block'>
<h3>test header</h3>
</div>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

Please Check whether it is going into the IF statement.

Comment: Answers should not be speculative. This kind of response is more suitable as a comment to the original post (question).

Comment: I do not have authority to comment on the question because of less than 50 reputations.

Comment: It is not going into the If statement.

Comment: It means the code you finding is not running because of statement so you are unable to see the changes   
if(($ptype=="" && $fullScreenEnabled!="true") || $ptype=="home" ||     $ptype=="viewMemberListing" || $ptype=="viewFullListing" || ($ptype=="showOnMap"      && $fullScreenEnabled!="true") || $ptype=="adminOptions"  ||     $ptype=="UpdateAdminOptions" || $ptype=="allMembers" || $ptype=="contactus" ||     $ptype=="page" || $_GET["cpage"]==1){

Comment: @user3176076 I got the part where u say that the code has to be in the if loop. but when i look at my code, I cant really figure out if its inside if out not. I will post the entire index.php. If you can check in that I would realllly appreciate that. Thanks mate

Comment: Sure give me your code and i will check it and solve it as soon as possible.

Comment: @user3176076 its added to the question.

Comment: I check your code and unable to find $ptype,$fullScreenEnabled varable.Please check whether you initialize or not. Your code not going in IF Statement so the error is with the conditions used by you in if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you need to test this out methodically. First you need to check if ANY changes you type are getting uploaded into the server and getting reflected on the website.

So edit your file again, type `die("Updated code");` as the first line of your index.php and save the file. In the dialogue box that comes up (the one of which you have the screen shot), Just click yes.

Now hard-refresh the page and see if the text "Updated code" shows up. If yes, then we can move to second step. If no, then you got either a permission or a cache issue. To resolve it might take more expertise than you have. You could check if correct file permissions are available (though I doubt that is the reason, since you will get warnings if thats the case). In any case, right click the file - select `File Permissions`  and make sure the write checkbox is checked (If you are unsure of your user then just check it for all three - user, group and public. Not very safe, but I do not think you are building the worlds most secure site at the moment in any case)

Next is to check if there is a cache issue. You can try opening the same URL is a different browser or you can try deleting all your cache and trying again.I do not think this might be a problem either (unless you have a caching layer like varnish or memcache and it is set up in a really really bad way)

This next thing is very important:

The more apparent reason seems to be that your code could possibly be wrong. You are thinking that the software is problematic that is why you are not seeing changes that you should. It is a common mistake that people think that there can be no problems with their code, but with everything else in the world. So I would advice you to start line by line debugging until you hit one line where what is printed is not what was expected. And begin from there.

Comment: "You could check if correct file permissions are available" if u mean to say that index.php should be writable, then yes. its writable. owner permissions>>write and read. Im following the rest of the things u mentioned

Comment: When i added die("Updated code");  and refreshed my webpage>> It did flash the code "die("Updated code");" for a second and then my website loaded. So im guessing the files are getting updated. @raidenace

Comment: @shrbisht yup, I thought so. Because if the file is not updating correctly, your FTP client would have thrown some error. Now, you will need to get into the tedious job of debugging. First check what is it that you expect to see, then work back from that point to see which line prior to it breaks.